# Generating image in Python using Pillow (PIL)

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to generate a 100x100 all-black image with Python (v2.7.2) and Pillow (v2.4.0) and I get a very weird result.

This is my code

```
from PIL import Image
im = Image.frombytes('L', (100, 100), bytes([0] * 100 * 100))
im.show()
```

This is my result (zoomed-in and please ignore the grey border - it comes from OS X Preview). The image should be black, but it is not.

What am I doing wrong?

[image: Image generated by Pillow; something's wrong]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The result of `bytes([0] * 10)` is the string `"[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]"`. So, the colors of your pixels are the ASCII codes of `'['`, `'0'`, `','`, `' '`, and `']'` symbols.

To get the byte string of zero bytes use `bytes("\x00" * 100 * 100)` instead. Here `\x00` is the byte with hexadecimal value `00`.

Actually you don't even need `bytes(...)` call. `bytes` is the type only in Python 3.x. In Python 2.7.x `bytes` is just an alias for `str`.

So, the final code should be:

```
from PIL import Image
im = Image.frombytes('L', (100, 100), "\x00" * 100 * 100)
im.show()
```